# Redirection cycle while using alias

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a home web-server.

My folder structure is the following:

```
/home/pi/www/
├── homeGUI
│   ├── backend /* Contains an express server listening on 8080 */
│   ├── frontend /* Contains an Angular application */
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── /* Other .js files */
│   └── scripts
└── index.html
```

while my site configuration is this one:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/pi/www;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    #intended to serve the angular application
    location /homeGUI/ {
        alias /home/pi/www/homeGUI/frontend/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /homeGUI/frontend/index.html; #this one is causing problems
    }

    #intended to serve the files in the www folder
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }

    #intended to serve the express server
    location /homeGUI/api/ {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080
    }
}
```

The configuration above can serve all 3 contents(the static index.html, the angular application and the express server).

The problem I have is when i navigate to a route of the angular application directly (or by refreshing the page while on that route) (es: `localhost/homeGUI/route1`) this cause a redirect cycle because it tries to redirect to /homeGUI/frontend/index.html which then falls into the same location rule and cycle.

All I want to accomplish is redirect every request like `/homeGUI/*` to the `/home/pi/www/homeGUI/frontend/index.html` file with the exception of `/homeGUI/api` which should go to the express server on port 8080.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element of your `try_files` statement should be the URI.

The URI for the file at `/home/pi/www/homeGUI/frontend/index.html` is `/homeGUI/index.html` and **not** `/homeGUI/frontend/index.html`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location /homeGUI/ {
    alias /home/pi/www/homeGUI/frontend/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /homeGUI/index.html;
}
```

---

The above may work, but using `alias` and `try_files` in the same block can cause problems due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

You can replace your `try_files` statement with default behaviour and an `if` block.

For example:

```
location /homeGUI/ {
    alias /home/pi/www/homeGUI/frontend/;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /homeGUI/index.html last; }
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Your first guess was right. By using `try_files $uri $uri/ /homeGUI/index.html;` I can directly load `localhost/homeGUI/route1` and it works like it should.